# Match subgroup with same name on separate conditions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to parse a cookie header I'm getting back that the cookies package complains about. I've come up with the following regex that works:

```
((?P<name>\w+)(=(\"(?P<value1>[\w;,#\.\/\\=]+)\"|(?P<value2>[\w#\.\/\\]+)))?)[;,]?
```

For an example, see this link to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2Ug9UP/1). Essentially, this works but I'd like to use `value` in place of both `value1` and `value2`. This shouldn't be an issue because it's impossible to generate a match on both subgroups at the same time (one is quoted and the other isn't). Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can match precisely what you need with a lookbehind:

```
(
  (?P<name>\w+)
  (
    =
    (?P<quote>"?)            # Match an optional quote, which we capture,
    (?P<value>               # then either
      (?<=")[\w;,#./\\=]+    # a quoted value, which follows a quote,
    |                        # or
      [\w#./\\]+             # an unquoted value, which is the fallback,
    )                        # and
    (?P=quote)               # the quote we captured or an empty string.
  )?
)
[;,]?
```

A value always follows `=`, so `(?<=")` matches *iff* it's a quoted value.

Note that you don't have to escape `/` (it doesn't mean anything special in Python flavor), `.` (inside a character class), nor `"` (if you use `'`, `'''` or `"""` as string delimiters).

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sbp6fy/1).

Alternatively, you can use the conditional group syntax:

```
(
  (?P<name>\w+)
  (
    =
    (
      (?P<quote>")?          # Match an optional group which contains a quote
      (?P<value>             # then
        (?(quote)            #                if group <quote> was captured
          [\w;,#./\\=]+      # a quoted value
        |                    # or
          [\w#./\\]+         # an unquoted value
        )                    #
      )                      # followed by
      (?(quote)(?P=quote))   # the same quote, if the group presents.
    )
  )?
)
[;,]?
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sbp6fy/2).

Answer (score 2):

Just place the *optional* quantifier, ?, after each of the quotation marks.

```
(?P<name>\w+)(=(\"?(?P<value>[\w;,#\.\/\\=]+)\"?|)?)[;,]?
```

Furthermore, I don't believe the additional capture groups are necessary.
And, you could decrease the character class requirement, using a lazy quantifier, ?.

```
(?P<name>[^ ]+?)=\"?(?P<value>.+?)\"?[;,]
```

An alternate method would be to preserve the quotation marks, and remove them from within the program.

```
(?P<name>[^ ]+?)=(?P<value>\".+?\"|.+?)[;,]
```

For reference, there is an *RFC* for *cookies*, which provides a definition for its syntax.
*[RFC 6265 – HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1)*.

It appears that the delimiting value is a semi-colon, ;.

```
cookie-header     = "Cookie:" OWS cookie-string OWS
cookie-string     = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-pair )

cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )

token             = <token, defined in [RFC2616], Section 2.2>

token             = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
separators        = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                  | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                  | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                  | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
```